# EF7-Beta6: Nested foreach fails by a use of an already open connection

Tags: entity-framework-core

Just trying to dump strings of the stored instances in a nested `foreach` loop.

```
foreach (var Company in db.Companies)
{
    Console.WriteLine($" - {Company.Name}");

    foreach (var Department in db.Departments)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($" - {Department.Name}");
    }
}
```

Just trying to access `db.Departments` ends up in a try to reuse an already open connection -> Error!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using SQL Server? If so, ensure your connection string contains `MultipleActiveResultSets=True`. This feature is known as [MARS](https://msdn.microsoft.com//library/cfa084cz.aspx).